# How to use MATLAB at host PC with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, ssh, pi-b+, matlab, scp

I'm trying to connect MATLAB with raspberry pi 2 b+. have already instlled the raspberry pi addon on MATLAB at the host LAPTOP.

The configuration -

**Matlab(Host LAPTOP)-<---->ETHERNET<---->RPI2_B+**

I didn't use the raspberry pi addon OS installation because the RPI is already operating with **Raspbian Jessie pixel**.

So I need to configure the RPI interface with Matlab.
Reading at this [LINK](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/182038-acessing-already-os-installed-raspberry-pi-using-matlab) got me to understand that the RPI needs to be configured with a "MATLAB Server" and a "MATLAB Daemon".

As the second command on the link describes, the command should look like this (also found that on matlab but no documentation is available)-

```
setupMATLABServer(ssh, scp)
```

The SSH is the RPI IP for my understanding, and the SCP is the command for coping files, so what should I put there to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Type in

```
targetupdater
```

in MATLAB and configure the settings.

MATLAB will download a file called `raspberrypi_firmware_16_2_0.zip`.

Unzip it and open the image file.

Copy the entire `/opt` to your existing installation.

The location `/opt/MATLAB/server_v16.2.0/` is where the binaries live.

To start MATLAB run

```
sudo /opt/MATLAB/server_v16.2.0/matlabd   <PORT NUMBER>
```

The port number is usually  `18732`  or the one you set.

To run the UDP daemon run

```
/opt/MATLAB/udp_ip /boot/iflist.txt
```

After this MATLAB should work.